# UIViewController displayed behind current view when presented modally

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

On iOS 5, when I try to present any view controller from another one, using `presentModalViewController`, the modal view is presented behind the current view.

Since it works fine on iOS 4 and knowing that `presentModalViewController` has been deprecated in iOS 5, I tried using `presentViewController` with no luck.

This is the first time I encounter this issue, any ideas on what could lead to this weird behavior?

Comment: Maybe you have some views at UIWindow?

Comment: @AliaksandrAndrashuk I'm not sure I'm getting what you mean here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the issue. For some awkward reasons, the `rootViewController` of the root window wasn't set properly, leading to strange behaviors with modal views.

What is the more puzzling is that it worked fine on iOS 4 so far and failed on iOS 5. I believe I'm still missing the true reasons leading to such trouble, but correctly setting the `rootViewController` in `AppDelegate` solved the problem.

Comment: I think this is my problem too this code `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];` is giving the error: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x718b9e0> on <UIViewController: 0x75b0f90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. How did you set it correctly?

Comment: Actually, I completely rewrote this part of the code. I do not know myself what was exactly went wrong and how I solved it... Sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: For posterity, here is how I fixed this problem. Search "hack" on the page to see implementation. https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake/blob/master/FDTakeExample/FDTakeController.m

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you have not set a proper modal presentation style.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalPresentationStyle

This sample should trigger a full screen modal over top of your existing view controller.

```
 [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
 ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working, the view is still presented behind anything else. But thanks anyway!

Comment: in what method are you trying to trigger your modal?  one thing I noticed testing was that I was not seeing my modal if I tried to call it inside of viewDidLoad, however I could see it if I'd call the modal in the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: The modal is triggered when the user presses as button, long after `viewDidAppear` was called. I have done that thousands of time with success, but today I'm missing something. This is what puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a button to present the view controller, but this should work if you are. Create a new function in your view controller like the one below. This instantiates your view and a navigation controller in your view so it can be dismissed afterwards.

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
    UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController] alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
   }
```

And then in viewDidLoad you'd have something like this (if you were presenting it from a button). The code below is for a UIBarButtonItem, but other buttons should work in a similar manner. Just make sure you set the action parameter to @selector(buttonPressed), or whatever the name of the function you want called when the button is pressed.

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]                                                                                  
target:self                                                                         
action:@selector(buttonPressed)];
```

Comment: I actually have the same code, appart from the `UINavigationController` instantiation. Sadly, adding it has no effect. Plus, in some cases, I present a `UIImagePickerController`, which doesn't need a navigationController. Using a `UIImagePickerController` is what led me to believe that the controllers were presented behind the current view, since in this case, the status bar disappeared, covered with the "Camera view".